# Dynamically attach a caption to image

Tags: html, css, vue.js, caption

First off, I have images (switches), which have names (K1,K2,K3,..). I'd like to attach the displayed name K1, to the respective (displayed) switch, just like it is illustrated in the picture below.

[image: illustration]

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
<div id="app">
 <fieldset style="background-color: rgb(181, 207, 209);">
 <h1>simTest server</h1>
     <hr>
     <div class="circuitplan">
         <div v-for="(val, key, index) in switchObj" v-bind:key="key">
               <div>
                 <span class="switch" v-bind:class="{ closed: val==='closed', opened: val==='opened', K1: key==='K1', K2: key==='K2', K3: key==='K3', K4: key==='K4', K5: key==='K5'}" @click="onSwitchClick(key)"></span>
               </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </fieldset>
```

What I tried before was that I put the name of the switches a.k.a. "{{ key }}" here:

```
<span class="switch" v-bind:class="{ closed: val==='closed', opened: val==='opened', K1: key==='K1', K2: key==='K2', K3: key==='K3', K4: key==='K4', K5: key==='K5'}" @click="onSwitchClick(key)">{{ key }}</span>
```

All names of the available switches were displayed, but chaotically. Another thing I tried was to use :hover to display the switches when hovering over them, as a (gotta admit bad) workaround.

Anyone having a good idea how to implement this 'feature'? Thx in advance!

Comment: You've tagged this as SVG but there's no SVG markup in the question.

Comment: the switches are .svg files but you are right, will edit it